# Array Error/Warning

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am receiving the following warning:

```
Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /data/9/1/115/118/1767118/user/1910351/htdocs/aw/home/wp-content/themes/awthemesnew/library/sidebars.php on line 183
```

Keep in mind I am editing a wordpress .php file. Here is the full code on line 183:

```
function theme_print_sidebar($name, $places) {
    $style = theme_get_option('theme_sidebars_style_' . $name);
    $place_count = count($places);
    if ($name != 'footer' && $place_count < 2) {
        theme_print_widgets(reset($places), $style);
        return;
    }
    ?>
```

Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value of $places is apparently null by the time you call reset.

Your code is saying "only call reset when the value of $place_count is less than 2". 
You're setting the value of $place_count via the statement:

```
$place_count = count($places);
```

We can infer that when count() is called on a null variable it returns 0.   Since 0 is less than 2, the following statement is executed:

```
    theme_print_widgets(reset($places), $style);
```

However, at this point the fact that $places is null is causing an error.  I would be curious to know under what circumstances $places is null.  Once you've got the answer to that you can decide how to handle that case.

Comment: Here is the page the error is happening on: http://www.aromaticwaters.com/home/product-category/diffusers/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had erased a command in the footer and when the code when looking for it, since it was gone, it gave me a array warning. Thanks for the help.